# How singleton in boost implement all singletons are initialized before main is called?

Tags: c++, boost, singleton

The source code of singleton of boost is [***there***](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/boost/serialization/singleton.hpp) ,I don't understand two notations in the source file below:

```
// ***include this to provoke instantiation at pre-execution time***
static void use(T const &) {};

BOOST_DLLEXPORT static T & get_instance() {
static detail::singleton_wrapper< T > t;
***// refer to instance, causing it to be instantiated (and
// initialized at startup on working compilers)***
BOOST_ASSERT(! detail::singleton_wrapper< T >::m_is_destroyed);
use(instance);
return static_cast<T &>(t);
}
```

Question is: How could this code force initialization of singleton in c++ before main()?What do these two notation mean?

Comment: This pattern is used in cereal's static_object.hpp also https://github.com/USCiLab/cereal/blob/master/include/cereal/details/static_object.hpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't. It's this line that does:

```
template<class T>
BOOST_DLLEXPORT T & singleton< T >::instance = singleton< T >::get_instance();
```

It creates a static object that is initialized by a call to `get_instance`. Since it's a class-static object, it's initialized before main.

Comment: Could you give me an definition of "class-static object".I'm afraid I don't understand this.Thank you.

Comment: @Mamrot: As in `class A { static int x; };`, the member `A::x` exists in only one instance within your program.

Comment: But the standard[3.6.2.3] says it is implementation-defined whether or not the dynamic initialization (8.5, 9.4, 12.1, 12.6.1) of an object of namespace scope is done before the first statement of main?

Comment: If the class-static object is initialized after main() it should be initialized before any use of function or object.So you are right,it's because of a call to get_instance. I get an egg in my face.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first comment actually refers to the line above,

```
BOOST_DLLEXPORT static T & instance;
```

which constructs a `static` instance of `T`. Statics are initialized before `main` is started, that's just a C++ rule.

Comment: I saw [6.7.4 initialization of local object with static storge duration] and [3.6.2 Initialization of non-local object] in C++ standard of 2003.In general,there is no fixed order between main and  dynamic initialization of object with static storge duration.

Answer (score 1):

You're just showing part of the code, which may explain why you don't understand.

Before a program is executed, it must first be loaded into memory. At that time, if a static or global scope variable is found, it is initialized with either the value specified or the default compiler.

Then if you specify a static instance of class, it's constructor will be called even before main!
That what boost uses to provide this functionality.

Comment: Sorry,my link to full source code is not clear,I edited the link word.Could you give me the reason of your answer?For example,from which item in the standard or other reasons.

Comment: I'v never read the standard, but I know computer infrastructure and a little about how things work. If you want your object to be initialized at launch, then it is created before the call to main. That must be found reading about global scope object or static variables.